# INSERT OR IGNORE with SQLModel using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlmodel

Does anyone know if its possible to get a `INSERT OR IGNORE` function with SQLModel? And if not, does anyone know if there is a workaround to get the same results?

I haven't tried anything to get the results I'm look for as I'm fairly new to programming. I just been reading of documentation.

If you have used SQLite before you know that `INSERT OR IGNORE` is a function that looks for the `primary_key` in your database and if it doesn't exist, it will insert the new data into the database, but if the `primary_key` does exist, it will completely ignore the data and prevent errors on your code.

Comment: a very common DB idiom is an `UPSERT` which [doesn't seem supported](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/59) yet, so presumably this isn't supported either